# How to completely remove docker from Oracle Linux 7

Tags: docker, oracle-linux

I installed docker on **Oracle Linux 7** with `sudo yum install docker` and thought I removed it with `sudo yum remove docker` but`/usr/bin/docker` is still there:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.11-ol, build 9bb540d
```

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962730/docker-not-completely-removed) for CentOS, but trying the answers there did not remove anything, see below.

```
$ sudo yum remove docker \
>               docker-client \
>               docker-client-latest \
>               docker-common \
>               docker-latest \
>               docker-latest-logrotate \
>               docker-logrotate \
>               docker-engine
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
No Match for argument: docker
No Match for argument: docker-client
No Match for argument: docker-client-latest
No Match for argument: docker-common
No Match for argument: docker-latest
No Match for argument: docker-latest-logrotate
No Match for argument: docker-logrotate
No Match for argument: docker-engine
No Packages marked for removal
```

And even the [documented](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#uninstall-docker-engine) solution:

```
$ sudo yum remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
No Match for argument: docker-ce
No Match for argument: docker-ce-cli
No Match for argument: containerd.io
No Packages marked for removal
```

How do I purge it from my system completely? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
sudo yum remove docker
sudo yum remove container-selinux containerd protobuf-c libnet criu runc docker-cli
```

This worked on my system, but a generic and more intuitive solution is still welcome. Also, some users may want to keep some dependencies.